# add queryset with queryset for each record in django

Tags: python, django

I have used Django to develop a web app.
In view, I have a queryset from all() function in a table.
For each query, I need to use a value to get another queryset in another table.

```
view.py:

def Browse_and_adopt(request): 
    query_results_book = Title.objects.all()
    course_id = Material.objects.filter(book_id=here should be the id each query in query_results_book).course_id
    title = CourseInfo.objects.filter(id=course_id).values(
        'title').distinct()

   //then I want to add title to each corresponding query
    


    query_results_book_json = serializers.serialize('json', query_results_book)

    return render(request, 'bms/inbox/Browse_and_adopt.html', {"query_results_book_json": query_results_book_json})
```

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use related_name https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/
and prefetch_related https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: the id of each query is not a foreign key in my case ,  actually in my title table there's no foreign key so I could not use prefetch_related

Comment: it's one to many relationship. so the foreign key is on another table